# Filter datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I know it is a stupid question but I can't get any idea even I asked Google.

Here's my scenario:

I have a table in my database named `Sales` with a column named `dateTime`.

The `dateTime` format is like this `2014-07-29 21:07:36.000`.

Now I wish to view all data in `2014-07-XX`.

Can anyone help? Thank you and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server doesn't have any *format* - it's an 8-byte binary value.

Comment: @marc_s Oh I thought it has a format because the `DATETIME` is generated from my vb.net application. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Select * from
sales
where Month(dateTime)=7 and Year(dateTime)=2014
```

Comment: Thanks for willing to help. It works and very simple :)

Comment: do you ever want to see cross/multiple month information?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `datediff`.

```
Select * from
sales
where datediff(mm, '01-jul-2014', [dateTime]) = 0
```

This would allow you to pass the comparison date as a parameter easily.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189794.aspx) -

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart
>   boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate

In this case we are using mm to get the difference in months of the two dates and checking that their difference is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT <YouColumns> FROM Sales 
WHERE dateTime >= '2014-07-01' AND dateTime < '2014-08-01';
```

This way SQL Server could even use an index on dateTime, if it had one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @From datetime='7/1/14'
    ,@To datetime='7/31/14'

Select *
FROM Sales
Where [dateTime]>=@From 
    and [dateTime]<@To+1 --to get last day greater than midnight.
```

This will capture all dateTimes including the last days timestamps.  You should probably not use dateTime as a column name.